# Attempting to plot the time on the x-axis of my line graph?

Tags: php, json, d3.js

Can anyone help?  I'm attempting to plot the time on the x-axis of my line graph. Completely new to JSON and PHP and having real problems with this.

At the moment y-axis depicts "reading":

```
    d3.json('getdata.php',function (jsondata) { 
    var data = jsondata.map(function(d) { return d.reading; }); 

    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(jsondata, function(d) { 
    return parseInt(d.reading); })]).range([height,0]);
```

The output from "getdata.php" is in the following format:

```
[{"reading":"10","Time":"2012-11-01 00:00:00"},{"reading":"10.2","Time":"2012-11-01 00:02:00"}......
```

I get a parse error if I change:

```
     var data = jsondata.map(function(d) { return d.reading; });
```

to

```
     var data = jsondata.map(function(d) { return d.Value; });
```

I know it may seem like a very simple question but how do I return both "reading" and "Time"?

Would also really appreciate any help with how to format/parse DateTime to depict Time only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't have to do anything to return both reading and time, your JSON object is already in that form. Maybe if you saw it in another form, you'd understand what I mean:

`[{"reading":"10","Time":"2012-11-01 00:00:00"},{"reading":"10.2","Time":"2012-11-01 00:02:00"}`

This is how JavaScript will see it:

```
[
  {
    reading: "10",
    Time: "2012-11-01 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    reading: "10.2",
    Time: "2012-11-01 00:02:00"
  }
];
```

If you pass this into `.data()`, you can access the individual properties by `d.reading` and `d.Time`.

For your call to `d3.max`, I'd just use `+d.reading` to convert reading to an int - either that, or be sure to provide the radix: `parseInt(d.reading, 10)`: